# Strapi Plugin Path Issue

Tags: strapi, headless-cms

I am trying a develop a plugin using strapi CLI.
Now after generating plugin, when I add its configuration in config/plugins.js like this

```
`module.exports = {
// …
‘my-plugin’: {
enabled: true,
resolve: ‘./src/plugins/my-plugin’
},
// …
}`
```

and after running the strapi, the .strapi\client\app.js file generates the path incorrectly like this

import myPlugin from “…srcpluginsmy-plugin/strapi-admin”;

How can I resolve this issue?

Cannot edit the app.js file as it is automatically generated by strapi.

Comment: what's your Node.js version and Strapi version ?